# Publishing/Deploying React JS Sitecore JSS app

Tags: jss

We are working on application using React JS for UI using Sitecore JSS. We are able to import the app into sitecore, could see content items created, published the website. 
We can run the app (hosted on IIS) can see every thing working.

If i want to host only the react js appl minus sitecore files, will that be possible? If yes please let me know the steps. It will be of great help?

Thanks in advance

Cheers,
Kiran

Comment: Do you mean you want to host your app in one or more cheaper nodeJS container/servers without Sitecore, and just use the Sitecore CD remote similar as calling an API?

Comment: that's correct. I think that's would be true headless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible there are multiple JSS application modes. It is called the `Headless server-side rendering mode` This is for running your app on any platform that supports node.js

You can use the [sample](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/dev/samples/node-headless-ssr-proxy) app 
It works as a HTTP proxy to the Sitecore server, proxying incoming requests to Layout Service, and then rendering the resultant JSON to HTML before returning it.

Comment: thank you Jan. It helps